# 80's Short TV story about a monster in the closet which grabs the mother during the day

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, tv, horror

I remember seeing this when I was really young, sometime between 1985-1989 but the show itself could be older of course as I know this was just something that was on TV.

I remember a boy thinking there was a monster in his closet. His mother of course doesn't believe him. I don't remember a father figure in this story but there might have been. The short ends with the boy going off to school, so it is daytime, and the mother goes to his room to clean it. She is picking up some toys, maybe like a fake brick or large Lego or something, so she is on her knees and like halfway in his closet just cleaning up and there it is. A monster, and it gets her, the end.

I remember this being so terrifying because it got her during the day, it wasn't your typical monster in the night thing and that just really stuck with me. I have checked every episode of all the standard 80's horror shows that had new episodes of the week and have come up with nothing. But honestly it feels like this was a very short story, even shorter than your typical 80's horror story of the week formula.

Answer (score 6):

I've never seen it myself, but was it the first episode of TerrorVision, "[The Closet Monster](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6926034/?ref_=ttep_ep1)"?

> A young boy who is not getting to sleep because he thinks there is a monster in his closet. The boy is right, with the monster getting his mother.

Her abduction can be seen around the 10:27 mark.

Comment: Big scary red eyes!

Answer (score -2):

**Monster in the Closet**

Directed by:    Bob Dahlin

Written by: Bob Dahlin

Produced by:
Peter L. Bergquist,
Michel Billot,
Terrence Corey,
David Levy,
Robert Rock,
Starring,
Donald Grant,
Denise DuBarry,
Claude Akins,
Howard Duff,
Henry Gibson,
Donald Moffat,
Paul Dooley,
John Carradine,
Frank Ashmore,
Paul Walker,
Jesse White,
Stella Stevens.

Cinematography: Ronald W. MacLeish

Edited by:
Mark Conte,
Raja Gosnell,
Stephanie Palewski,
Jacque Elaine Toberen.

Music by:   Barrie Guard

Distributed by: Troma Entertainment

Release date:   October 31, 1986

Running time:   89 minutes

Country:    United States

Language:   English

Comment: Does it have a scene at the end where the mother is snatched?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  I don't know

Comment: :) Basically just that we all for answers that address the question. Right now, the only commonality is that it's a film and there's a monster in the closet.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots yep but we wont know what it is until we watch it.

Comment: You can read the summary at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monster_in_the_Closet, which doesn't seem to have the scene being referenced.